# JQUERY How do I fadeout on post success?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I want to fade out my div once the button inside it is clicked, and the resulting post request returns successful.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
            var u_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.post("actdeact.php",{do_action:'activate',uid:u_id},function(data){
                $(this).fadeOut("500");
                alert('loaded '+data);
            });
        });
```

since the divs are dynamically generated I used a class instead of an id (or each()). But it seems I cannot use $this for the fadeout.....any ideas?

Comment: **EDIT:** Deleted my answer. See [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595792/jquery-how-do-i-fadeout-on-post-success/4595869#4595869) for a working answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
            var that=$(this);
            var u_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.post("actdeact.php",{do_action:'activate',uid:u_id},function(data){
                that.fadeOut("500");
                alert('loaded '+data);
            });
        });
```

The idea is to get the reference to $(this) before calling $.post

Comment: looks like a scope issue, when you are calling $( this ) inside the post callback function you are not inside the scope of your selector anymore, you are inside the scope of your post callback function so this is referring to the callback not the .btn element.

do as suggested above and it should fix this.
hope my explanation makes sense.

Comment: @Alex Vidal Your statement is not true. `that` is declared inside the function and will hold a reference to the button to which click event is attached to.

Comment: You're correct, my mistake. Deleting my comment and my answer.